# $scope not updating after passing to new view with $location.path

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-routing

I have a simple CRUD I put together with Angularjs. From a product list display I pass the user to a new view template for the "Create New" form.

The form processes fine and updates the database. I then pass the user back to the list display using "$location.path(url)".

For some reason when the list page displays, the changes do not appear in the $scope and you have to refresh the page to see the changes.

Sample code:

```
    $scope.acns = acnFactory.query()
    .$promise.then(function (data) {
        $scope.acns = data;
    });
```

the above displays the list of items.

```
$scope.createAcn = function () {
    $scope.acn.isActive = true;
    acnFactory.create($scope.acn);
    $location.path('/acn');
}
```

The above POSTs the new product then redirects to the list page (/acn)

My assumption is that the list page will reprocess or watch the changes to the $scope but the view does not update.

Comment: what is difference between $scope.acn and $scope.acns ?

Comment: $scope.acns represents all products. $scope.acn is a single product. In the first code block I call the list of acns. In the second code block I am processing a form to "create new" acn. Then I pass back to the /acn view, which lists all acns.

Comment: it might happen that as its a async call our $scope may not get updated ,try using $scope.$apply() after     $scope.acns = data; ,just to check weather it do the trick

Comment: Thanks maddygoround. I actually tried that with no results.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most probably here:

```
$scope.createAcn = function () {
    $scope.acn.isActive = true;
    acnFactory.create($scope.acn);
    $location.path('/acn');
}
```

creating a product most certainly consists in sending an HTTP request to the server. This is asynchronous. This means that `acnFactory.create()` returns immediately after the request has been **sent**. Not after the response has been received.

So, this code sends the request to create the product and immediately goes to the page which lists the products. The GET request sent to get the product list is thus sent almost at the same instant as the one used to create the new product. The two requests are handled concurrently by the server, and the returned list contains the list without the new product, which is being created in a separate transaction.

You need to wait for the response to come back, and make sure it's successful, before going to the product list. Assuming the service returns a promise, as it should do:

```
$scope.createAcn = function () {
    $scope.acn.isActive = true;
    acnFactory.create($scope.acn).then(function() {
        $location.path('/acn');
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks JB. Really appreciate it. I actually figured it out and used the following code:      $scope.createAcn = function () {
        $scope.acn.isActive = true;
        acnFactory.create($scope.acn)
        .$promise.then(function () {
            $scope.acns = acnFactory.query()
            .$promise.then(function () {
                $location.path('/acn');
            });
        });
    }

Comment: JB, Needless to say, your code code was a lot better than what I came up with and it helped me slim things down. Thanks!!!